# Cleartool findmerger command not working

Tags: clearcase

I was trying to copy my ClearCase view from one server to another server.

But the command for `findmerge` is not working and gives error.

Can anyone help me out on this ?

Here is the error message in full:

```
/home/xkuldub 23>cleartool findmerge `cleartool find -avobs -ele 'brtype(xkuldub_vse_4.0_integration_sds_GIC)' -print -nxname`
cleartool: Error: Cannot get view info for current view: not a ClearCase object.
cleartool: Error: Pathname required.
Usage: findmerge -graphical
       findmerge {pname ... | [pname ...] -all | -avobs}
                 {-ftag view-tag |-fversion version-selector | -flatest}
                 [-depth | -nrecurse | -directory] [-follow] [-visible]
                 <general options>
       findmerge activity-selector ... -fcsets
                 [-ftag view-tag |-fversion version-selector | -flatest]
                 <general options>
                 [-user login-name] [-group group-name] [-type {f|d|fd}]
                 [-name 'pattern'] [-element query]
                 [-nzero] [-nback] [-whynot] [-log log-pname]
                 [-c checkout-comment | -cfile pname | -cq | -cqe | -nc]
                 [-unreserved [-nmaster]] [-query | -abort | -qall | -qntrivial]
                 [-serial] [{-btag | -fbtag } view-tag]
                 {-print [-long | -short | -nxname]
                 | {-merge | -okmerge} -blank_ignore
                 | {-gmerge | -okgmerge}
                 | -exec command-invocation
                 | -ok command-invocation
                 | -co
                 } ...
```

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on:

- what is your ClearCase version (7? 8? 9?)
- what is your client OS? Your ClearCase server OS?
- how you moved your view to another server (for instance, did you follow "[Moving a view to a host with the same architecture or to a NAS device](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSH27_7.1.2/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_admin.doc/topics/t_viewadm_mv_1arch.htm)" or "[Moving a view to a host with a different architecture](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSH27_7.1.2/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_admin.doc/topics/t_viewadm_mv_2arch_ux.htm)"?)

Your view needs to be properly registered in order for the cleartool command to recognize the current folder as part of a view.

Answer (score 0):

The main reason this isn't working is that your current directory is not in a clearcase view. Findmerge needs a view context to resolve the merges that need to be done.

Start with the embedded find command to get it working, and then branch out.

You also need an action for findmerge to perform, like -merge, -gmerge, or -print.

Be aware that passing a large changeset this way could fail depending on the maximum allowed command line length. If this is a UCM environment, you could do this cross-stream merge either through deliver or findmerge {activity list} -fcsets.